# How can I improve my LED display code so that it reacts in real-time

Tags: performance, assembly, microcontroller, pic, microchip

This is a carry on question from [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621679/how-can-i-exit-my-lookup-table-instruction-with-the-desired-value-on-pic16f1829) and I was wondering how I can go about improving my code, which currently has an extreme delay in outputting the numbers to the display and also not showing the expected outputs under all situations, i.e., some segments are not lit up.

Please see the images below!

[image: Correct but delayed output 1]

**Correct but delayed output 1**

[image: Correct but delayed output 2]

**Correct but delayed output 2**

[image: Correct but delayed output 3]

**Correct but delayed output 3**

[image: Incorrect and delayed output]

**Incorrect and delayed output**

From an inexperienced point of view, I imagine that it's a timing issue. But, how I go about solving it isn't quite clear to me at the moment. Therefore, any insights or proposed numbers that I can use will be very much appreciated.

The working code with the ADC code block is below:

```
LIST        p=16f1829   ;list directive to define processor
#INCLUDE    <p16f1829.inc>  ;processor specific variable definitions

__CONFIG _CONFIG1, (_FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOREN_ON & _CLKOUTEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF);
__CONFIG _CONFIG2, (_WRT_OFF & _PLLEN_OFF & _STVREN_OFF & _LVP_OFF);

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; UDATA_SHR declares a section of shared (all across the banks) uninitialised data
INT_VAR     UDATA_SHR   ; INT_VAR is the section name in ACCESS RAM
TempC       RES     1   ;
L0          RES     1   ;
w_temp      RES     1   ; variable used for context saving
pclath_temp     RES 1   ; variable used for context saving
status_temp RES     1   ; variable used for context saving

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

LEDtrisA    EQU     TRISA
LEDtrisC    EQU     TRISC
LEDlatA     EQU     LATA
LEDlatC     EQU     LATC

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

RESET_VECTOR    CODE    0x0000
    GOTO    START   ; When using debug header, ICD2 may not stop
                    ; on instruction 0 during reset.

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

INT_VECTOR      CODE    0x0004  ; Interrupt vector location

ISR             ; Relocatable Interrupt Service Routine
                ;   Context saving for ISR
    MOVWF   w_temp      ; save off current W register contents
    MOVF    STATUS, w   ; move status register into W register
    MOVWF   status_temp ; save off contents of STATUS register
    MOVF    PCLATH, w   ; Saves value in register PCLATH
    MOVWF   pclath_temp

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

;   If the interrupt came from the timer, execute the TMR0 interrupt 
;   service routine. 

    BANKSEL     TMR0
    MOVLW       .96
    MOVWF       TMR0
    BTFSC       INTCON, TMR0IF  
    CALL        Service_TMR0    
    BRA         UpdateDisplay   ; Refresh the display

UpdateDisplay
    BANKSEL     LATA        ; Selects memory bank containing LATA register 
    MOVF        LEDlatA, w  ; display status -> w register
    ANDLW       0x0f        ; Separate the lower half byte
    MOVWF       TempC       ; Save display status in TempC
    BSF         TempC, 4    ; Beginning status of LSD display
    RRF         TempC, F    ; Set the status of the next display
    BTFSS       STATUS, C   ; C = 1?
    BCF         TempC, 3    ; If not, turn off the LSD display
    BTFSC       TempC, 0

    BRA         UpdateMsd   ; If it is turned on, display the MSD
                        ; digit of the number
UpdateLsd
    BCF         TempC, 3    
    BSF         TempC, 1                
    BTFSS       STATUS, Z   ; If it is, skip
    MOVF        L0, w       ; Third LSD digit -> w
    ANDLW       0x0f        ;   /
    BRA         DisplayOut  ; Show it on the display

UpdateMsd
    SWAPF   L0, w       ; MSD figure - >
    ANDLW   0x0f        ;   /
    BTFSC   STATUS, Z   ; MSD = 0?
    MOVLW   0x0a        ; If it is, skip

DisplayOut
    CALL    LedTable    ; Take the mask for a digit
    MOVWF   LEDlatC     ; Set the mask on port B
    MOVF    TempC, W    ; Turn on displays
    MOVWF   LEDlatA
    BRA ISR_END

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISR_END
;   Restore contents before returning from interrupt    
    MOVF    pclath_temp,w   ; PCLATH is given its original content
    MOVWF   PCLATH
    MOVF    status_temp,w   ; STATUS is given its original content
    MOVWF   STATUS
    SWAPF   w_temp,f        ; W is given its original content
    SWAPF   w_temp,w

    BSF     INTCON,GIE  ; Global interrupt enabled
    RETFIE              ; Return from interrupt routine

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; LOOKUP TABLE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

LUT_VECTOR  CODE    0x0030  ; Lookup Table location

LUT                         ; Lookup table is at the top of third page, 
                            ; but can be placed at some other place, it
                            ; is important to have it all on one page

LedTable
        ADDWF       PCL, F
        RETLW       B'00111111' ; mask for digit 0
        RETLW       B'00000110' ; mask for digit 1
        RETLW       B'01011011' ; mask for digit 2
        RETLW       B'01001111' ; mask for digit 3
        RETLW       B'01100110' ; mask for digit 4
        RETLW       B'01101101' ; mask for digit 5
        RETLW       B'01111101' ; mask for digit 6
        RETLW       B'00000111' ; mask for digit 7
        RETLW       B'01111111' ; mask for digit 8
        RETLW       B'01101111' ; mask for digit 9
        RETLW       B'01110111'
        RETLW       B'01111100'
        RETLW       B'00111001'
        RETLW       B'01011110'
        RETLW       B'01111101'
        RETLW       B'01110001' 
        RETLW       B'00000000' ; no digit ......   

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

MAIN_PROG   CODE

START

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ERRORLEVEL -302     ; Disable warning accessing register not in bank 0
    BANKSEL OSCTUNE     ; Configure OPTION_REG and TMR0
    MOVLW   0x00        ; Set oscillator to factory calibrated frequency
    MOVWF   OSCTUNE     ;
    BANKSEL STATUS
    ERRORLEVEL +302     ; Enable warning accessing register not in bank 0

CLEAR_RAM                   ; code sequence initialises all GPR's to 0x00   
    MOVLW       0x70        ; initialise pointer
    MOVWF       FSR0        ; to RAM
    CLRF        FSR0H

NEXT
    CLRF        INDF0       ; Clear INDF0 register
    INCF        FSR0L, F    ; Inc pointer
    BTFSS       FSR0L, 7    ; All done?
    GOTO        NEXT        ; No, clear NEXT

CONTINUE                    ; Yes, CONTINUE
    NOP

 ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; MAIN BODY OF PROGRAM
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Setup main init
    BANKSEL     OSCCON      ; Selects memory bank containing OSCCON register 
    MOVLW       b'01011000'     ; Set CPU clock speed of 500KHz -> correlates to (1/(500K/4)) for each instruction
    MOVWF       OSCCON          ; OSCCON <- 0x38

; Configure the ADC/Potentimator
                            ; Already in bank1
    MOVLW   b'00001101'     ; Select RA4 as source of ADC and enable the module (careful, this is actually AN3)
    MOVWF   ADCON0
    MOVLW   b'00010000'     ; Left justified - Fosc/8 speed - vref is Vdd
    MOVWF   ADCON1
    BANKSEL ANSELA          ; Selects memory bank containing ANSELA register 
    
; Setup pins as digital I/O 
    MOVLW   0x10        ; Selects memory bank containing ANSELA register 
    ANDWF   ANSELA      ; All pins are digital
    CLRF    ANSELC

; Configure the input & output pins 
    BANKSEL     TRISA           ; Selects memory bank containing TRISA register 
    MOVLW       b'11111100'     ; RA0 and RA1 are configured as outputs and
                            ; used for 7-segment display multiplexing
                            ; RA2 is input push-button for initialization
    MOVWF       TRISA
    CLRF        LEDtrisC    ; Port C is output


    BANKSEL     LATA        ; Selects memory bank containing LATA register 
    CLRF        LEDlatA     ; Set all outputs to "0"
    CLRF        LEDlatC ;
    BSF         LEDlatA, 1  ; Turn on MSD display 

; Setup Timer0 as the delay
    BANKSEL     OPTION_REG
    MOVLW       b'10000100'     ; TMR0 is incremented each 32us (Fclk=8MHz)
    MOVWF       OPTION_REG  ; ps = 32

    BANKSEL     TMR0        ; Selects memory bank containing TMR0 register
    BSF         INTCON, GIE     ; Global interrupt enabled
    BSF         INTCON, TMR0IE  ; Timer TMR0 interrupt enabled

MAINLOOP
    BRA         MAINLOOP    ; Continue forever

A2D:
; Start the ADC
    NOP                     ; Requried ADC delay of 8uS => (1/(Fosc/4)) = (1/(500KHz/4)) = 8uS
    BANKSEL     ADCON0      ; Selects memory bank containing ADCON0 register 
    BSF         ADCON0, GO      ; Start the ADC
    BTFSC       ADCON0, GO      ; This bit will be cleared when the conversion is complete
    GOTO        $-1             ; Keep checking the above line until GO bit is clear

; Grab Results and write to the LEDs
    SWAPF       ADRESH, w       ; Get the top 4 MSbs (remember that the ADC result is LEFT justified!)
    MOVWF       L0
    RETURN

; TIMER 0 Interrupt routine clears the TMR0 interrupt flag.
Service_TMR0:
    BANKSEL     INTCON
    BCF         INTCON, TMR0IF  ; MUST ALWAYS clear this in software or else stuck in the ISR forever
    BTFSC       LATA, 1     ; Check if ADC value already determined
    CALL        A2D             ; Get the ADC result
    RETURN          

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; END OF PROGRAM
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    END         ; End of program
```

Comment: Always provide your code with the question. Liking to it generally isn't sufficient.

Comment: Many thanks. Wasn't sure whether people would appreciate me repeating the code!

Comment: No worries. Interesting question, but I'm no electronics guru, so unfortunately I can't help with the question. As for formatting, your question should be self-contained. It is fine to refer back to the original question, but for help with code, the code should always be in the current question `:)`

Comment: Will keep that in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: please describe what this is doing at a high level.  adc and leds, what is in between what is the adc sampling, etc.  I have a blah, I am taking an analog sample of blah and I want to display blah, and how I am doing that at a high level is...and then based on that there may be questions on specific detail.

Comment: Those images of your wiring are worse than useless; they are distracting.  They actually detract from your question.

Comment: @old_timer, do you have any information on how I can go about learning electronics by myself in a structure and coherent manner? Cause, that would be very much appreciated and would make my learning less haphazard!

Comment: Does anyone know why my question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some issues that some may be bad practices.

1- Here you call the ADC routine in the Timer0 ISR.

```
Service_TMR0:
    BANKSEL     INTCON
    BCF         INTCON, TMR0IF  ; MUST ALWAYS clear this in software or else stuck in the ISR forever
    BTFSC       LATA, 1     ; Check if ADC value already determined
    CALL        A2D             ; Get the ADC result
    RETURN
```

Then the Timer0 isr calls ADC and the program loops in there at least 20us approximately which can lead to miss another pending interrupts or pending input events.

```
A2D:
; Start the ADC
    NOP                     ; Requried ADC delay of 8uS => (1/(Fosc/4)) = (1/(500KHz/4)) = 8uS
    BANKSEL     ADCON0      ; Selects memory bank containing ADCON0 register 
    BSF         ADCON0, GO      ; Start the ADC
    BTFSC       ADCON0, GO      ; This bit will be cleared when the conversion is complete
    GOTO        $-1             ; Keep checking the above line until GO bit is clear

; Grab Results and write to the LEDs
    SWAPF       ADRESH, w       ; Get the top 4 MSbs (remember that the ADC result is LEFT justified!)
    MOVWF       L0
    RETURN
```

As far as I see you do everything in the timer isr which is a bad programming practice. You update the display as well. Updating the display doesn't take much time so it can be ignored in the isr. But some routines wihch take much time should not be processed within the isr. Therefore you better process the routines which can take more time or can poll a flag within your main loop.

2- In this section you multiplex the digits. You multiplex them using RRF instruction as if there are 4 digits, but you have only 2 digits in your application.

```
UpdateDisplay
    BANKSEL     LATA        ; Selects memory bank containing LATA register 
    MOVF        LEDlatA, w  ; display status -> w register
    ANDLW       0x0f        ; Separate the lower half byte
    MOVWF       TempC       ; Save display status in TempC
    BSF         TempC, 4    ; Beginning status of LSD display
    RRF         TempC, F    ; Set the status of the next display
    BTFSS       STATUS, C   ; C = 1?
    BCF         TempC, 3    ; If not, turn off the LSD display
    BTFSC       TempC, 0
```

I don't know which pins are used for multiplexing the digits, but you must set the correct bit in Temp register in order to multiplex them correctly. For example if your digit1 and digit0 connected to A1 and A0 respectively, You must  set the second bit Tempc,2 in order to multiplex them correctly. Then when the set bit reaches to carry then you must set it again and so forth.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your points. I'm a novice at this so any advise on good practices is what I'm looking for and are very much appreciated. You are right in your assumption that digit1 and digit0 are connected to RA1 and RA0 respectively.

Comment: Not at all. The PIC Assembly was my start point in learning embedded programming. Assembly is much more flexible than the high level languages but more time consumer at the same time. However knowing a programming language only does not suffice most of the time. You must learn and improve algorithms and tecniques which will help you translate a real world problem into an embedded environment solution by utilizing each little piece of hardware and code and convert them into a one, united and harmonized construct step by step.

Answer (score 1):

aLoHa,

There are any number of ways to multiplex 7-segment LED displays with a PIC controller.

Here is a demo of my favorite method:

```
;
; File:     main.asm
; Target:   PIC16F1829 
; Author:   dan1138
; Assembler: MPASMWIN v5.81
; IDE: MPLABX v5.04
; 
    LIST        p=16f1829   ; list directive to define processor
    LIST        n=0, c=250  ; make list file look nice
    LIST        r=dec       ; use decimal as default radix for numbers
    errorlevel  -302        ; suppress warning for: Register in operand not in bank 0.
;
;                           PIC16F1829
;                +-------------:_:-----------+
;      5v0 ->  1 : VDD                   VSS : 20 <- GND
;          <>  2 : RA5/CPP2      PGD/AN0/RA0 : 19 <> ICD_PGD
;      POT <>  3 : RA4/AN3       PGC/AN1/RA1 : 18 <> ICD_PGC
; ICD_MCLR ->  4 : RA3/MCLR     CCP3/AN2/RA2 : 17 <> SW  
;    SEG_F <>  5 : RC5/CPP1          AN4/RC0 : 16 <> SEG_A
;    SEG_E <>  6 : RC4               AN5/RC1 : 15 <> SEG_B
;    SEG_D <>  7 : RC3/AN7           AN6/RC2 : 14 <> SEG_C
;    SEG_G <>  8 : RC6/AN8      SDI/AN10/RB4 : 13 <> DIGIT1
;          <>  9 : RC7/AN9/SDO   RX/AN11/RB5 : 12 <>
;          <> 10 : RB7/TX            SCK/RB6 : 11 <> DIGIT2
;                +---------------------------+
;                            DIP-20
;
; Description:
;
;   This is code to demonstrate one method to multiplex
;   two digits in two 7-segment LED displays.
;
;   A segment is ON when the SEG(A-G) output is HIGH.
;
;   A digit is on when the DIGIT(1,2) output is HIGH.
;   Only one DIGIT output can be HIGH at a time.
;

#INCLUDE    <p16f1829.inc>  ;processor specific variable definitions

 __CONFIG _CONFIG1, (_FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOREN_ON & _CLKOUTEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF);
 __CONFIG _CONFIG2, (_WRT_OFF & _PLLEN_OFF & _STVREN_OFF & _LVP_OFF);

RES_VECT  CODE    0x0000            ; processor reset vector
    pagesel START
    GOTO    START                   ; go to beginning of program

ISR_DATA  UDATA_SHR
WREG_Save   res 1
STATUS_Save res 1
PCLATH_Save res 1
Segments    res 2

ISR       CODE    0x0004            ; interrupt vector location
    movwf   WREG_Save
    movf    STATUS,W
    movwf   STATUS_Save
    movf    PCLATH,W
    movwf   PCLATH_Save

    pagesel $
    btfsc   INTCON,TMR0IE
    btfss   INTCON,TMR0IF
    goto    ISR_EXIT
    bcf     INTCON,TMR0IF
    
    banksel LATB
    movlw   0x80
    andwf   LATC,F                  ; Turn off all LED segments
    movlw   (1<<LATB6)
    btfsc   LATB,LATB6
    movlw   (1<<LATB4)
    btfsc   LATB,LATB4
    movlw   (1<<LATB6)
    xorwf   LATB,W
    andlw   (1<<LATB4)|(1<<LATB6)
    xorwf   LATB,F                  ; Select LED display to be on

    btfsc   LATB,LATB6
    movf    Segments+0,W
    btfsc   LATB,LATB4
    movf    Segments+1,W

    iorwf   LATC,F                  ; Turn on LED segments for selected digit

ISR_EXIT:
    movf    PCLATH_Save,W
    movwf   PCLATH
    movf    STATUS_Save,W
    movwf   STATUS
    swapf   WREG_Save,F
    swapf   WREG_Save,W
    RETFIE


MAIN_PROG CODE                      ; let linker place main program
;
; Setup system clock at 32MHz
;
START:
    clrf    INTCON
    banksel PIE1
    clrf    PIE1
    clrf    PIE2
    clrf    PIE3
    clrf    PIE4

    banksel OPTION_REG
    movlw   0xFF
    movwf   OPTION_REG

    banksel OSCCON                  ; Setup 32MHz system oscillator
    movlw   0xF0
    movwf   OSCCON
;
; Setup GPIO ports
;
    banksel LATA
    clrf    LATA
    banksel TRISA
    clrf    TRISA
    bsf     TRISA,TRISA2
    bsf     TRISA,TRISA4
    banksel ANSELA
    movlw   0xFF
    movwf   ANSELA
    bcf     ANSELA,ANSA2            ; Make SWn a digital input

    banksel LATB
    clrf    LATB
    banksel TRISB
    clrf    TRISB
    banksel ANSELB
    clrf    ANSELB

    banksel LATC
    clrf    LATC
    banksel TRISC
    clrf    TRISC
    banksel ANSELC
    clrf    ANSELC
;
; Setup TIMER0 to interrupt every 1.024 milliseconds
; when the system oscillator is 32MHz.
;
    banksel OPTION_REG
    bcf     OPTION_REG,TMR0CS
    bcf     OPTION_REG,PSA
    bcf     OPTION_REG,PS0
    bcf     OPTION_REG,PS1
    banksel TMR0
    clrf    TMR0
    bcf     INTCON,TMR0IF
    bsf     INTCON,TMR0IE
;
; Turn on interrupts
;
    bsf     INTCON,GIE
;
; Setup LED displays to show '1' and '2'
;
    movlw   1
    call    Hex2Segments
    movwf   Segments+0
    movlw   2
    call    Hex2Segments
    movwf   Segments+1
;
; Application process loop
;
AppLoop:
    GOTO    AppLoop
;
; Function: Hex2Segments
;
; Input: WREG = LED segment table lookup index
;               Range: 0x00 to 0x0F
;
; Output WREG = 7 low bits are LED segments gfedcba
;
Hex2Segments:
    andlw   0x0F
    xorlw   HIGH(SegTable)
    movwf   PCLATH
    xorlw   HIGH(SegTable)
    xorwf   PCLATH,F
    addlw   LOW(SegTable)
    btfsc   STATUS,C
    incf    PCLATH,F
    movwf   PCL

SegTable:
    RETLW   B'00111111' ; mask for digit 0
    RETLW   B'00000110' ; mask for digit 1
    RETLW   B'01011011' ; mask for digit 2
    RETLW   B'01001111' ; mask for digit 3
    RETLW   B'01100110' ; mask for digit 4
    RETLW   B'01101101' ; mask for digit 5
    RETLW   B'01111101' ; mask for digit 6
    RETLW   B'00000111' ; mask for digit 7
    RETLW   B'01111111' ; mask for digit 8
    RETLW   B'01101111' ; mask for digit 9
    RETLW   B'01110111'
    RETLW   B'01111100'
    RETLW   B'00111001'
    RETLW   B'01011110'
    RETLW   B'01111001'
    RETLW   B'01110001' 


    END
```

This method does the HEX to segment lookup outside of the ISR.

This keeps the ISR execution time short.

I did not include functions to read the ADC but there is an example of how to display a one and a two on the LED displays.

The kind of 7-segment displays your are using and how they are wired is not clear to me so I doubt this code will work in your breadboard.

Comment: Hi Dan, many thanks for your input. My code works as desired now. But, it's always useful to know of more than one way to resolve a problem. Btw, your code would work fine on my breadboard with a slight modification to it, using PORTA pins for the multiplexing, as opposed to PORTB pins, as you have done.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering what is the determining factor for the clock speed that one uses, aside from speed of computation? Why would one use 32MHz, instead of 16MHz, or even 8MHz or 4?

Comment: @aLoHa, selecting the system clock frequency of an embedded controller depends on many, sometimes conflicting needs of an embedded application. My general approach is to use the highest available frequency until I encounter a compelling reason to use something slower.